# list iterating exception so the loop keeps going, geocode

Tags: python, loops, exception, geocode

I have a list of place names and I want to iterate over it to get the coordinates:

```
import time
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="xxx")
for a in pl:
    location = geolocator.geocode(a)
    print(location.latitude)
    time.sleep(2)
```

Now it works for the first few entries, then I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'latitude'
```

I assume that that particular entry is not in a format that can be interpreted. How can I make my loop go on in those cases and just leave the entry black for these one, or just delete the entry outright.

Comment: You need to learn  about the `try ... except` construct.

Comment: Thank you very much, will immediately do that !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if location is not None, and then only get the latitude attribute from it

```
import time
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="xxx")
for a in pl:
    location = geolocator.geocode(a)
    #If location is not None, print latitude
    if location:
        print(location.latitude)
    time.sleep(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the access to `location.latitude` inside a try/except block:

```
for a in pl:
    location = geolocator.geocode(a)
    try:
        print(location.latitude)
    except AttributeError:
        print('Skipping bad location...')
    time.sleep(2)
```